# Validation rule for dropdownlist in yii2

Tags: validation, yii2

This is my drop-down list:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'course')->dropDownList($dataPost, ['prompt' => 'Select a Course']); ?>
```

How can I put a validation rule in model so it gives error when a 'course' is not selected on form submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that the attribute `course` is required in the model using the rules method:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['course'], 'required'],
    ];
}
```